# Why is Jumbotron height not reduced for smaller screens in this solution?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to reduce Jumbotron size for various screen sizes in Twitter Bootstrap (latest 3.x.x version). The viewport breakpoints do get triggered now e.g. for `display: none` on a section, but the Jumbotron size doesn't change. What's the problem here?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
  .jumbotron {
  height: 30%;
  height: 30vh;
  }
}
```

and this being my usual settings

```
.jumbotron {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: #41A4DA;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 70%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**min-height** remains 70vh, **height** tries to be 30vh, 
putting min-height in media query block should work.

Also, please make sure that @media query block is parsed after .jumbotron class in the css file.

[https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp](http://min-height%20property%20prevents%20the%20value%20of%20the%20height%20property%20from%20becoming%20smaller%20than%20min-height)